# How to allow leniency in an input query?

Tags: javascript, json

I want users to be able to input a name and have the code work even though the name is not the exact same as the one in the dataset. For example: inputting "Camden" works, but inputting "camden" does not work and returns an error.

How to make the code allow for example a non capitalized letter or even a wrong letter?

```
    app.get("/api/borough_by_name", function(req, res){
    // set the type of content in the response
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    // read input parameter from request
    var name = req.query['name'];

    // validate input, check if the parameter is valid or not
    if (name === undefined){
        // return error as a JSON string
        var str = JSON.stringify( {"error":"Parameter 'name' is not defined."} );
        res.end( str );
    }

    var borObj = null;
    // loop over the statesData GeoJSON structure
    for (i in londonBoroughs.features){
        var feat = londonBoroughs.features[i];
        if (feat.properties.NAME == name){
             borObj = feat;
             continue;
        }
    }

    if (borObj == null){
        // borough not found, return an error as a JSON string
        var str = JSON.stringify( {"error":"NAME '"+name+"' doesn't exist. Please check the spelling."} );
        res.end( str );
    }       

    var respJson = {};
    respJson["results"] = [ borObj ];
    res.end( JSON.stringify( respJson ) );
```

Comment: You'll have to decide for yourself on exactly what your criteria for "leniency" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way you can do is to compare both variables with uppercase: str.toUpperCase();

So, it will match any letter capitalized on the name, CamDen, camDEn, etc.

```
feat.properties.NAME.toUppercase() == name.toUppercase()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error using that "feat.properties.NAME.toUppercase() == name.toUppercase() is not a function"

Comment: Luffydude, the function is toUpperCase() and not toUppercase (the C is a capital letter), also to use the toUpperCase() function, the property must be a string, cannot be an object. Make a console.log(feat.properties.NAME) and check if echo an string or an object.

Comment: now the server runs with the upper case C but tried using the line between the "var feat" and the "for", it still returns the error saying it does not exist. Should the line go somewhere else?

Comment: it cannot be between "var feat" and "for" because "feat.properties.NAME" is declared only after the "var feat"

Comment: oops sorry, my bad in explaining. It did not put it between "var feat" and "for" but I put it between "var feat" and "if" and it didn't work

Comment: var borObj = null;
  // loop over the statesData GeoJSON structure
  for (i in londonBoroughs.features){
   var feat = londonBoroughs.features[i];
   feat.properties.NAME.toUpperCase() == name.toUpperCase();
   if (feat.properties.NAME == name){
     borObj = feat;
     continue;
   }
  }

Comment: the expression must be inside the if statement, like: if(feat.properties.NAME.toUpperCase() == name.toUpperCase()) {...}

Comment: Boom! Perfect! Works like a charm! You sir are a genius, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string methods [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) for case normalization:

```
> var name = "Camden"
> name.toLowerCase() === "camden"
true
```

For wrong letters you can look at the [levenshtien distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which you can find many implementations of, for examle https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein.

Answer (score 0):

To check if only one letter is wrong:

You can use **Levenshtein distance** algorithm which calculate a distance between 2 strings.

```
if (getDistance("camden", "calden") === 1) { … }
```

With [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927) (the first one).

---

To compare 2 strings without case sensitive check:

```
if ("Camden".toLowerCase() === "camden") { … }
```